# Using Windows Kits 10, where is winapifamily.h?

Tags: c++, windows, sdk

I was trying to use [Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240.0)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).
File `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h` includes `winapifamily.h`

```
//-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
//
// Windows API Partitioning and ARM Desktop Support
//
//-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
#ifndef _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP
    #ifdef WINAPI_FAMILY
        #include <winapifamily.h>
        #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM) 
            #define _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP
        #else
            #ifdef WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP
                #if WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP 
                    #define _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP
                #endif
            #endif
        #endif
    #else
        #define _CRT_USE_WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP
    #endif
#endif
```

Where can I find `winapifamily.h`?

**Context**
Our project is normally built with mingw+gcc or Android toolchains (gcc or llvm), and with minimum changes (to CMake files and source code) we are targeting a build with:

- [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) with [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) generator
- [LLVM 32bit for Windows](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html), version [3.9.1](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.1/LLVM-3.9.1-win32.exe)
- [Windows SDK 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
- Visual Studio 2015 (still not clear to me if this is really necessary)

Comment: in `10.0.10240.0\shared` not exist ?

Comment: @RbMm No, there's no shared folder in the SDK 10... I do have it here though: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include

Comment: are wdk installed ?

Comment: @RbMm No, should they?

Comment: install it. it install to same folders as sdk. this help

Comment: @HansPassant I would rather not use the IDE (I am using cmake with LLVM, in a project normally built with mingw-gcc), but thank you for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: You don't need to know, it's not a header you need to be concerned with. On a broader scale, something is wrong with your build system configuration. What build system are you using?

Comment: @IInspectable CMake with ninja generator + LLVM 32bit for Windows, version 3.9.1 + Windows SDK 10 + Visual Studio 2015 (if necessary, still not clear to me)

Comment: That's valuable information, that needs to be edited into your question.

Comment: @IInspectable Done!